# With Ticker in select, time.After doesn't work

Tags: go

I encountered this problem while trying `time.Ticker`.

As codes below, `case <-time.After(time.Millisecond * 5500):` never executes, the program prints "ticker" and "chan" repeatedly.

Can anyone explain this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 2)
    defer ticker.Stop()
    ch := time.Tick(time.Second * 3)
    for {
        select {
        case t := <-ticker.C:
            fmt.Println("From ticker:", t)
        case t := <-ch:
            fmt.Println("From chan:", t)
        case <-time.After(time.Millisecond * 5500):
            fmt.Println("timeout, exit")
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
From ticker: 2021-02-02 11:31:55.9902354 +0800 CST m=+2.002391201
From chan: 2021-02-02 11:31:56.990678 +0800 CST m=+3.002835701
From ticker: 2021-02-02 11:31:57.9900811 +0800 CST m=+4.002240701
From chan: 2021-02-02 11:31:59.9901219 +0800 CST m=+6.002285301
From ticker: 2021-02-02 11:31:59.9901219 +0800 CST m=+6.002285301
From ticker: 2021-02-02 11:32:01.9901347 +0800 CST m=+8.002301901
From chan: 2021-02-02 11:32:02.990973 +0800 CST m=+9.003142101
From ticker: 2021-02-02 11:32:03.9899932 +0800 CST m=+10.002164201
From ticker: 2021-02-02 11:32:05.9911548 +0800 CST m=+12.003329601
From chan: 2021-02-02 11:32:05.9911548 +0800 CST m=+12.003329601
From ticker: 2021-02-02 11:32:07.9898197 +0800 CST m=+14.001998301
```

Comment: `time.Millisecond * 5500` is equivalent to 5.5 seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is working as expected. Your first two cases always produce a value in less than 5500ms, so no, `time.After` will never produce a value.

Each time the `select` is encountered, a *new* channel is returned by `time.After` which will emit a value in 5.5 seconds. You never actually wait 5.5 seconds, as the two tickers always emit values first, so the `time.After` branch of the `select` never executes and that channel is discarded.

Comment: Thought I'd share the code to fix it: https://play.golang.org/p/yE9F5vGmhvF

Comment: Thanks a lot! I mistakenly create a new timer using time.After in each "select" block, thus it never reaches 5.5s.